# What causes this NullPointerException in my Java program?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class listjava
{
   public static void main(String args[]){
       Console c = System.console();
       char[] pw;
       pw = c.readPassword("%s","pw: ");
       for (char ch: pw)
           c.format("%c ",ch);
       c.format("\n");

       MyUtility mu = new MyUtility();
       while(true)
       {
           String name = c.readLine("%s","input?: ");
           c.format("output : %s \n",mu.doStuff(name));
       }
    }
}

class MyUtility{
    String doStuff (String arg1){
        return " result is " + arg1;
    }
}
```

I got an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at listjava.main(listjava.java:7)
```

Why is my program wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.console()` is returning null.

Quoting Java's documentation:

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine, if any.

So, there are probably no console associated to your **JVM**. You are probably running your program within **Eclipse** or other **IDE**. Try running your program from your system's command line. It should work.

To run your program from the command line.

1. Go to directory where `listjava.class` resides
2. Run java's interpreter

   $ java listjava

Comment: Thank you, you're right. One more question? Why is this wrong when I using IDE? thanks!

Comment: It's not **wrong**. It's just that your **IDE** does not give the **JVM** a console when running a program inside it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Javadoc for `System.console()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29):

> Returns: The system console, if any, otherwise null.

So I suppose that `System.console()` is handing back `null` and your line

```
pw = c.readPassword("%s","pw: ");
```

is therefore dereferencing `null`.  I'm not sure what fix you might want to use; perhaps reading from `System.in` instead?